# Nginx return 502 but not 500

Tags: django, nginx

I use django and nginx to offer service.

when use dev environment(python manage.oy runserver) and do something wrong, it can return 500 error.

however when use nginx+django and do the same, it return 502.

How can I config nginx.conf to let it return 500? my config is as below:

```
upstream veevaqa.veevaorion.com.upstream
 {
    server 60.205.56.175:8000 weight=1;
 }
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  veevaqa.veevaorion.com;

    location /nginxstatus{
        access_log on;
        auth_basic "nginxstatus";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
     }
    location / {
       index index.jsp;
       proxy_pass   http://veevaqa.veevaorion.com.upstream;
       proxy_redirect             off;
       proxy_set_header           Host $host;
       proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       client_max_body_size       10m;
       client_body_buffer_size    128k;
       proxy_connect_timeout      300;
       proxy_send_timeout         300;
       proxy_read_timeout         300;
       proxy_buffer_size          4k;
       proxy_buffers              4 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
   }
```

}

Comment: It will still throw a 500 error, regardless of whether you're running the dev server or if it's behind a WSGI type server. 502 means bad gateway, so chances are your gateway wasn't running. Check your logs for more info.

Comment: ths @Keenan Lawrence, I check the nginx error.log and can see nothing, but access.log have a record to show this 502 error.  does nginx intercept my server error code and trans it to 502?

Comment: Nope. What are you using to bind to port 8000? gunicorn? Make sure that the process is running.